# Apache ErrorLog skip logging specific message

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, apache2

For one of my Apache vhosts, the error log is bloated with messages about "favicon.ico". I don't need these logged. I'm aware of the `SetEnvIf` directive that can be applied to `CustomLog`.

Here's my config for the `SetEnvIf` option and `CustomLog` directive

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ".*/favicon\.ico.*" DontLogThese
# Other SetEnvIfNoCase matches with DontLogThese
...
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/apache2/access_log 86400" combined env=!DontLogThese
...
```

This is working for the "access_log" file, but I need to eliminate these messages from the error log as well. `ErrorLog` only takes one argument, the file name.

Comment: One way would be to provide a favicon.ico.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille , Thank you. These aren't 404 type error messages. There're rules that prevent some external access to resources. The Apache errors are AH01630 and AH01753, denied by server configuration.